# How to find elements of one ArrayList in another and add the matched elements in new Collection?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have two String ArrayLists: `A` for words and `B` for sentences. I need to find the elements of ArrayList `B` which contain the elements of ArrayList `A` and add them into a new collection `C`.

The main question is, how can I iterate two collections simultaneously and find whether `B` contains elements of `A`?

Comment: You could use nested `for` loops...

Comment: So, you need the words that matched with sentences to be in Collection C?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: @RohitGaikwad, I need the sentences which contain the words to be in collection C.

Comment: Improved grammar/spelling/punctuation. Question still needs more code from author, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> b=new ArrayList<String>();

    //new Collection
    ArrayList<String> c=new ArrayList<String>();

    a.add("hi");
    a.add("there");
    a.add("how");
    a.add("are");

    b.add("how are you?");
    b.add("I'm fine!");
    b.add("What about you");
    b.add("Hello you there?");

    for(String s: b){
        for(String s2: a){              
            if(s.contains(s2)){
                c.add(s);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Output: `[how are you?, Hello you there?]`

Comment: @thatfella16, is this you want?

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks a lot!